# Maya calendar won't start

Tags: calendar

Yesterday when I was using Maya for the first time, it would immediately start and allow me to add remote calendars to it. I even was able to add an event to a remote CalDAV calendar.

At some point there must have been a problem so that the application won't start anymore. When I try to start Maya now, I get the below output on the terminal and then the application gets stuck:

```
$ maya-calendar

** (maya-calendar:3902): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-KGJ9tku41s: Connection refused
[_LOG_LEVEL_INFO 18:14:09.083533] Application.vala:155: Calendar version: 0.3.1.1
[_LOG_LEVEL_INFO 18:14:09.083680] Application.vala:157: Kernel version: 4.2.0-42-generic
```